# Creating a DDoS attack using DirectConnect

Tags: tools, ddos, p2p, flooding

I have been trying to hack around with Apex DirectConnect. What I wish to do is to utilize the querying nature of P2P apps like DC to generate a DDoS attack (see links for reference [here](https://stormsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2008/08/dc_ddos_v2.pdf), [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1146847.1146894) and [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5273837)).

To quote from one of the references:

> These are the steps of a file download in DC protocol:
> D = downloader
> U = uploader
> H = hub

1. D>H: $ConnectToMe <U's username> <D's IP and port>|
2. H>U: $ConnectToMe <U's username> <D's IP and port>|
3. U>D: TCP Connection to D’s IP and port

> ...

> The attack uses a vulnerability in the DC++ hubs (Verlihub-0.9.8c, Verlihub-0.9.8d-rc1, Ynhub <
> 1.0306, Ptokax < 0.3.5.2), respectively in the Client-to-Client communication described above.
> The vulnerability is in step 2, when the hub forwards the $ConnectToMe request to the Uploader client
> without verifying it. So the Downloader can put any IP address and port it wants in the $ConnectToMe
> request and the receiving client (Uploader) will connect to that address, trying to continue the file
> download protocol....

But I am falling short of a good tool which will allow me to tamper/forge packets for my purpose.

[ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) gave me good hope, but I guess the project isn't maintained anymore.

Any suggestions on what tools will allow me to tamper with all kinds of packets?

---

**Edit:** Being concerned over the low views and no answers/comments, I felt that I should clarify what I am looking for- I need something  on the lines of what Wireshark does as a packet sniffer- sniffs all varieities of packets. But I don't want to just sniff packets, I want to tamper them. There are many available tools to tamper with HTTP requests (like
[fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software))). But I need something to deal with *all* kinds of protocols - IP, TCP, UDP and HTTP headers and payloads.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It can do all you request and more and is under active development.

"Scapy is a powerful interactive packet manipulation program. It is able to forge or decode packets of a wide number of protocols, send them on the wire, capture them, match requests and replies, and much more."